# Why using "Async" into a WebService

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

I learned today from Steve Smith on PluralSight course: AspNet Core 6 Web API: Best practices that is recommended to use Async the most you can on a WebService.

If I'm not wrong, in C# ASP.NET, a new WebService request is affected to a worker thread and there is no UI waiting to be refreshed.

I don't understand why I should use await when the request is synchronous and requires only one thread? If I'm already running into a worker thread where there is no UI that needs to be responsive, why await is preferable? Adding thread switching would add time to the final time to process a request?

I undestand to work in parallel we need threads (or tasks). But I don't see where await would makes sense on a request where there is no need to parallelism. Why using "async" either if the awaited job takes long time if the thread would not do anything other than wait for the job to be executed before continuation?

I'm missing something but I don't know what?

Comment: If the operation is doing something asynchronous that can be off-loaded from the thread (database operations, file operations, etc.) then making it `async` would allow the web service to free up the thread to handle other incoming requests.  If the API has high traffic volume, not blocking threads is a good thing.

Comment: In request/response systems (not just web-applications), the advantage of using asynchrony is to allow threads to be re-used to service other concurrent requests while they're waiting/blocked on IO - because allocating new threads is surprisingly expensive (e.g. 256KB-1MB RAM for each thread, so you won't want to use 1,000 threads to service 1,000 concurrent HTTP requests). This isn't new: BSD Sockets supports nonblocking network IO using `select`, for example.

Comment: @Dai, Thanks, it makes sense! Yes it does need ~lots of memory but I think although it is mostly the stack, it would be backed up and could only be a few 4k pages in real memory. But still, it makes sense to not create any if not required. Thanks!

Comment: @David, Thanks, it makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 type of workloads you should consider when working with async - CPU-bound and IO-bound ([Asynchronous programming scenarios: Recognize CPU-bound and I/O-bound work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#recognize-cpu-bound-and-io-bound-work)).

CPU-bound usually means that the execution of code is dependent mainly on the CPU. For example, calculating the digits of PI to a certain length would be CPU-bound. This is the "go to" case when using `async` is appropriate for UI scenarios to keep application responsive.

On the other hand IO-bound means that the execution is dependent on some input/output system, such as disk drives when reading a file or a networking adapter when making to some resource like a database (or another HTTP request).  The "go to" case here is for example web service which reads data from the database. The goal here is not responsiveness but "performance" (actually throughput - you do not block server thread while waiting for IO response and it can serve other request to the web service, which can positively affect the load which server can handle). Obviously if no IO operation is needed to handle some web request then making the endpoint (action in controller or minimal APIs handler) asynchronous does not have any benefits (it can even negatively affect the performance but the effect is negligible in most cases).

Read more:

- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)